# Limit jQuery toggle to only affect one accordion

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

So there's a page I'm working on which contains several accordions. You can check it out right here:

http://leda.rewind9.com/impact/admissions-data/

If you click on one of the accordions, you can notice all chevron arrows are animated at the same time. ¿How can I limit my toggleClass to only affect the accordion I clicked on?

Here's my code:

```
$('.panel-heading').click( function() {
    $(".fa-chevron-right.rotate").toggleClass("down");
} );
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Add HTML too with CSS(if required) or create live demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you have selected all the `.fa-chevron-right.rotate` instead of the one which you clicked.

the below code should do the trick.

```
$('.panel-heading').click( function() {
    $(this).find(".fa-chevron-right.rotate").toggleClass("down");
});
```

Comment: You are totally right, this works!